# Amazon S3 Upload not working

Tags: vb.net, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload sample PDF files to Amazon S3 and it's failing.

```
Dim putRequest1 As PutObjectRequest = New PutObjectRequest()
putRequest1.BucketName = "fneticket"
putRequest1.Key = "test_FN_key"
putRequest1.FilePath = "C:\Temp\ABELGAS-0065796409909.pdf"
putRequest1.ContentType = "application/pdf"
putRequest1.Metadata.Add("x-amz-meta-title", "test_FN_S3_Upload")
Dim response1 As PutObjectResponse = client.PutObject(putRequest1)
```

I'm also not sure if there is anything else I need to add. What is 'Key'? Do I just add a random key for now?

Comment: The key is probably your API key tied to your account.

Comment: Please see [mcve]. Are there any error messages?

Comment: after executing line Dim response1 As PutObjectResponse = client.PutObject(putRequest1) i am getting error  'System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' any idea?

Comment: the "putRequest1.Key" here is the object key (or the filename) of the file that you are uploading to S3 bucket.